# Scraping chat file: How to automatically add missing usernames

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, telegram

I have a local html file containing messages from a telegram chat.

I scraped each message and extracted information like ID of the message, date it was posted and the content of each message.

The Problem: If a user posts multiple times in a row, only the first message will contain the user's name. After that, the name-column in the df remains empty- Because: All the following messages have their own ID and time stamp – but they do not have the div class="from_name" information.

Is there a way to fix that so that each message has a user name information in the df?

```
messages = doc.select('div.message')


rows = []

for message in messages:
    print('---')
    
    row = {}
    
    row['id_number'] = (message['id'])
    
    try:
        row['time'] = (message.select_one('div[title]').get('title'))
    except:
        print("Couldn't find the time")
    
    try:
        row['username'] = (message.select_one('div.from_name').contents[0].strip())
    except:
        print("Couldn't find a name")
        
    try:
        row['text of the message'] = (message.select_one('div.text').text.strip())
    except:
        print("Couldn't find a text")    
    
    print(row)
    
    rows.append(row)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it in your `DataFrame` or explicitly in your code - Instead the `try/except` blocks you can check directly if element is available, if not set the `username` from last added `row` in `rows`:

```
if message.select_one('div.from_name'):
    row['username'] = message.select_one('div.from_name').contents[0].strip()
else:
    row['username'] = rows[-1].get('username')
    print("Couldn't find a name, set last username")
```

---

EDIT: Based on your comments you could check `len(rows)` and `continue` with next iteration if it is empty:

```
if message.select_one('div.from_name'):
    row['username'] = message.select_one('div.from_name').contents[0].strip()
elif len(rows) > 0:
    row['username'] = rows[-1].get('username')
else:
    continue
```

Comment: I get an error message. Pointing to the line after "else". 

Saying: list index out of range

Comment: Maybe because the first message of the chat is always the chat name which has no user name.

Comment: That is something we do not know, cause there is no detailed info or example in the question. But if this is a fact, simply handle it, while skipping the first one.

Comment: Is there a way to skip x-number of rows until the first message with a username pops up? Because in some chats (I have dozens of chat files) the first message will be the chat name and than there will be messages like "user x added user y"... Sometimes the first message with a username can be the second one, sometimes the fifth one.  Thanks

Comment: It is, but it would be guessing, if there are no detailed information in the question themselfe - So this would be my last response, check the edit in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I try to be more precise next time.